# Windows cannot access \\Shared Folder - How to remove the saved credentials of sharing?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, network-shares, windows-server-2012

My PC name is PC2 and there is a shared folder called PC1Shared on PC1 and I have a full permission to access that folder, However i am always having the following  error message:
Windows cannot access \PC1\PC1Shared

[image]

Any Advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how to delete the saved credentials of PC1 on PC2:

On PC2 in command prompt :

```
C:\>control keymgr.dll
```

The Credential Manager appears :

[image]

Move to Windows Credentials and remove the legacy login credentials.

Access the shared folder again and enter the permitted  login credentials.

In windows server 2012, you might need to restart the **Workstation** service.

Comment: Great answer, @Ala.  Another method (not as elegant, but sometimes easier) is to map the drive and provide the new credentials.  You don't need to keep it mapped - Windows should remember the credentials the next time you access it as a UNC path.

Comment: Removing the saved credentials from Credential Manager did not cause File Explorer to ask me for new credentials. Restarting the Workstation service seems to be the only way to force File Explorer to "forget" the old credentials. Thanks for the tip!